# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Fib'

Tags: python

I have just started programming in python and have the following problem: I have written an simple function abc.py:

```
def Fib(n):
    if n<2:
        return n
    else:
        return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
```

which I would like to import in another python file hi.py:

```
import abc

x = abx.Fib(4)
print(x)
```

Then the error written in the title appears. I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2016.2.1 if thats important to know.

Comment: You've got a typo in the code: `abx.Fib` instead of `abc.Fib`

Comment: What's `abx`? Shouldn't that be `abc`? Also, the full traceback might contain some clues.

Comment: There is a standard module named `abc` in Python. To avoid name conflicts, please choose a different name for your module (e.g. `abcd.py` or `fib.py`).

Answer (score -1):

Oops, it's a typo!

```
    x=abx.Fib(4)
```

should be:

```
    x=abc.Fib(4)
```

The lesson here is to proofread a little more closely, and pay attention to those pesky error messages :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be `NameError: global name 'abx' is not defined` rather than an AttributeError on the presumably non-existent and unimported module??

Comment: Just so you know, typo questions should generally be closed instead of answered. Though, as Two-Bit mentions, this wouldn't fix the error in OP's question, because if this was the solution, they would be getting a different error.

Comment: Go figure there's already an abx module, lol. Should have taken my own advise about reading the error message.